# CIContext from OpenGL Core profile (OpenGL 3.2)

Tags: macos, opengl, core-image, opengl-3

Is it impossible to use a CIContext, created with contextWithCGLContext from an OpenGL 3.2 core profile ?

My code works fine with legacy profile and crashes on CIImage drawImage when I switch to core profile.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that CoreImage can't render to a core profile context.

According to the answer in the link, you may have to resort to IOSurfaces to transmit data from CI<->GL3.

http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/CdR6fGkL9xkezE7HnXiG

Comment: the link is expired.